# What font is being used in Glide (the video messaging iphone app)?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I'm referring to the font used in the list items (The Crew, Chad Henderson, etc).

Trued using WhatTheFont, but too many options come up.

Is this just San Francisco font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font to me looks like [Gerbera](http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/brownfox/gerbera) but your picture is somewhat fuzzy.  If that is the picture you're referencing you might want to take a better/clearer screenshot to use on whatthefont:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This looks like Avenir (I believe all the text on the screenshot is Avenir apart from the status bar and logo). The bowls on the letters are very geometric (but wide), and the terminus of letters like a, c, s is basically perpendicular to the direction of the stroke. The middle stroke on the letter 'a' also doesn't rise up in the middle like the 'a' in Proxima Nova (another font I briefly thought it might be) or Gerbera.

I'm positive it's not Gerbera (the currently accepted answer) - look at the letters 'M' (legs are parallel), 'f' (unusually tall), 'c' and 't'.

It's also definitely not San Francisco, which is more rectangular generally, with higher x-height/shorter ascenders. 'f' and 'C' are good indicators here.

Comment: I agree. Avenir is also one of iOS's standard fonts so it's not an unreasonable assumption.